# Why are Conda Virtual Environments so big?

Tags: python, conda

Out of curiosity I just compared the size of a virtual environment directory created by Conda with one that was created by virtualenv.

```
$ conda create -p venv_conda python=3.6

$ python -m virtualenv venv_virtualenv
```

The size of the *conda* environment on Windows 7 is `110MB` while the *virtualenv* environment only takes `22MB`. That's five times as much. Does someone know why there is so much space needed by the conda environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read an answer in here https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2yurjj/conda_environment_vs_virtualenv/

which states:

> A good advantage of conda environment is that it not only installs python libraries, but also dependencies (like Qt when installing PyQt). It makes installation so much easier that you should use conda when possible.

If that still applies, that will be the reason for that massive difference between the virtualenv environment and the conda one.

Comment: Python virtualenv will do: if no --copies specified, it will sym link python executable, and it won't copy python's library, which contains all standard library and lib-dyn. And also, no ldd python's dependancies. So make python's venv is not able to copy to other boxes.

Comment: @Shuo Do you mean the `--always-copy` option? It makes no difference if   I activate it or not. The size of my *virtualenv* environment is 22MB. The Python executable gets coppied and not symlinked (Currently on Windows, Linux might be different)

Comment: python -m venv --copies. Windows is different, some symlink implementation is broken. @MrLeeh